# Output added to display & symbology applied only when output is a Model Parameter

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4

When I run my model the output is not added to display even though the Add to Display option is checked. Also, symbology applied from a layer I specified is not showing. Checking the Model Parameter option solves both of these issues. However, since I am going to publish the model as a geoprocessing service I don't want the user to have the option to mess with the name and location of the output.

It is not the first time this is happening nor am I the only one it happens to so I don't think there is a problem in my model.

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1.